# Пишу игру на Android и столкнулся с проблемой отрисовки в цикле - не выводится изображение на экран

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Создал цикл который будет отрисовывать блок(100 на 100) каждые 100 пикселей всего их должно быть 10,но при записи в цикл почему-то ничего не отображается, а без цикла работает(но мне же 10 блоков нужно, а не 1),ума не приложу чего делать,помагите пожалуйста,вот код отрисовки:

```
@Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {            
         canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
         pos=0;//переменная для цикла 
while(pos<10){   
         xd = xd + width;//положение блока по x равно положению на данный момент + ширина, дабы сделать чтобы они прикасались друг к другу.
         canvas.drawBitmap(dirtes, xd , 290, null);//dirtes - bitmap 
         pos++;
 }
```

Comment: Какое начальное значение xd?

Comment: Переменная Xd равна 0.

Comment: А `width` откуда берете?

Comment: Переменная width - это размер блока,то есть 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед циклом обнулите переменную `xd`, а лучше перенесите её объявление внутрь этого метода, если Вы не используете её значение после отрисовки для чего-то ещё (именно значение, а не саму переменную). Сейчас с каждым кадром она всё дальше и дальше убегает за пределы экрана - поскольку хранит последнее значение с предыдущего выполнения метода.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {            
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    pos=0;//переменная для цикла 
    //либо возвращаем x-координату к левому краю
    // xd = 0;
    //а лучше объявляем здесь локальную переменную, которая будет существовать
    //только пока выполняется этот метод:
    int xd = 0;
    while(pos<10){   
        xd = xd + width;//положение блока по x равно положению на данный момент + ширина, дабы сделать чтобы они прикасались друг к другу.
        canvas.drawBitmap(dirtes, xd , 290, null);//dirtes - bitmap 
        pos++;
    }
}
```

P.S. Правила хорошего тона рекомендуют всегда объявлять переменные там, где они нужны, максимально-возможно минимизируя их область видимости. Переиспользование переменных не даёт никакого выигрыша, а только запутывает код и приводит к ошибкам, вроде Вашей.